# Micro service management

Tags: web-services, nginx, mule

We are developing a merchant application in that we have various modules like Schedule, Booking, Invoice e.t.c, each of this module are runs in different server, those are exposed through as RESTful granular services. UI layer will communicate with these granular service accordingly. To identify the request and redirect to specific micro service runs in service layer of various sever we have created a service gateway. Some of the service required data manipulation on the go which is presently accomplished through Mule ESB and some routing activities are also managed through it.

Actual purpose of the Service gateway is to match the request with service dictionary available and redirect to the respective micro service, at present its been developed in j2ee framework and runs in wildfly server. So to achieve the same process in light weight manner we come across a micro service manager like"getKong" and Customising "nginx" server to manage microservices, Mule ESB.

Along with Service Bus management is it advisable to use the Mule ESB as MicroService maanager as like getKong or any other valuable suggestion ?

Answer (score 1):

In my personal opinion, you have three options:

1. If you don't need to perform authentication/authorization or/and
   Throttling and your routing can be quite complex/complicated than is
   completely fine to do it in Mule ESB.
2. If you do just URL rewrite nginx is probally the best choice for
   minimum overhead and maximum performances.
3. If you really need an API manager with all the rich features than is
   fine getKong or, if you want to stay in the MuleSoft
   world and your are willing to pay, you can have a look at [API
   Gateway](https://docs.mulesoft.com/anypoint-platform-for-apis/api-gateway-101).

Hope this helps